# Mirror implemented in A-frame is reflecting a more contrast boosted reflection of the real space

Tags: three.js, aframe, virtual-reality

I was creating a virtual room with aframe and to implement the mirror I used  Diarmid's code: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/diarmidmackenzie/aframe-multi-camera@latest/src/mirror.min.js and also tried this user's code too https://github.com/juunini/aframe-mirror/blob/main/aframe-mirror.js. They worked normally but when I put renderer="colorManagement: true" the reflection of my room seen in the mirror had different contrast. I will leave the link to the glitch site below.
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/fast-able-paneer?path=index.html%3A22%3A14

Comment: I believe what you're seeing here is a bug in the 'mirror' components that you're trying to use, related to incorrect color space assignments. Fixing that bug would likely require fixes to those libraries, a bit beyond what can be answered in an SO answer. I would suggest reaching out to the authors.

Comment: I reached out to Diarmid and he resolved the bug. The reason behind the bug was the latest update in the THREE.js library. Here is the link to the branch with the updates which is to be merged to the main branch as of now: https://github.com/diarmidmackenzie/aframe-multi-camera/blob/updated-three-reflector/src/mirror.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reached out to Diarmid and he resolved the bug. The reason behind the bug was the latest update in the THREE.js library. Here is the link to the branch with the updates which are to be merged to the main branch as of now: https://github.com/diarmidmackenzie/aframe-multi-camera/blob/updated-three-reflector/src/mirror.js

link to the main branch: https://github.com/diarmidmackenzie/aframe-multi-camera/blob/main/src/mirror.js